# django_filters custom method field name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

When I run this code I get **[invalid name]:** in the filters popup in django rest-framework views.

I would like to display the name **"find"** instead.
How can I set this name?

```
class MyModelFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    search_name = filters.CharFilter(field_name='name', lookup_expr='icontains')
    find_anywhere = filters.CharFilter(method='look_anywhere')

    def look_anywhere(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(Q(name__icontains=value) | Q(description__icontains=value))

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = {'search', 'find_anywhere'}
```

when calling

```
/api/mymodels/?find_anywhere=something
```

it works fine.

It is only the name of the filter in the DRF views:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

```
search_name = filters.CharFilter(field_name='name', lookup_expr='icontains', label="Put Label Here")
```